Effects of making a copyright claim under a fictitious name
In the United States, the author of a work has published it with a claim like this:

Copyright © 2024 Dubious Publishing Company.

Dubious Publishing Company is not an incorporated entity in any jurisdiction. The author of the publication is unambiguous, and Dubious Publishing Company appears to be a pseudonym under which they are conducting business. Assume that they have not filed a trade name / fictitious name / "doing business as" in any jurisdiction.

Who owns the copyright of this item?
Does the author lose any copyright protections by claiming that another entity owns the copyright? (Both rights and penalties for infringement.)
Does the author claiming in print that someone else owns the copyright have any effect on the actual ownership of the copyright?


We don't have enough facts about what is really going on to provide a meaningful answer.

Assuming a Berne Convention jurisdiction, the author owns the copyright unless they've transferred it to someone else. I don't think the erroneous copyright notice changes that, although it may affect the kind of damages they can get due to infringement.

"However, they have not filed a trade name / fictitious name / "doing business as" in any jurisdiction."  Are you 100% certain of that?  Is it possible they could be a sole proprietorship working from home under a business license issued by the town of Neah Bay WA?  Because if so it seems that answers to the first 3 questions are obvious.  (and really, the 4th as well...)

@MichaelHall If this is a hypothetical, I think we should assume the given premises are true. It's their hypo, they get to set the scene.

@barmar, Fair enough.  Follow up question then:  Is it a requirement to be "incorporated" in order to hold a copyright if you are not the author?  It seems that must be answered before any others.  (But then a good answer would take that into consideration I guess...)

I'm confused by the downvote. Is there a way I could improve my question?



Who owns the copyright of this item?


The author barring any transfer of copyright.


Does the author lose any copyright protections by claiming that another entity owns the copyright?


No.


Does the author claiming in print that someone else owns the copyright have any effect on the actual ownership of the copyright?


No.


Does such a claim effectively create an unincorporated association?


No.
You do not need to put a copyright notice for a work to be protected. Putting a notice has no legal effect. A notice does not have to use the correct name, pseudonyms are allowed.

In U.S. law there are some slight effects for including a copyright notice, when it comes to remedies for pre-notice infringements. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_notice Otherwise, I'd agree.
